# Identifying Matrix element links/connection MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I have a correlation Matrix:

```
A = [1 2 1 3 1 2 4 3 5 1; 
     2 3 4 5 6 6 6 7 7 8];
```

I need to find out how many times each individual element of row 1 is linked to elements in row 2.

For example, here element 1 in row 1 is related to the following elements of row 2, {2, 4, 6, 8}, so total 4 elements.

Similarly 2 is linked to {3, 6}, for a total of 2 elements.

Resulting Matrix C should be:

```
[element name in 1st row; Number of connection].
```

In previous example, `C = [1 2 ....; 4 2 ...]`;

Since actual matrix size is of the order of 1000s', it is impossible to do manually. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What if the column `[1;2]` appears twice? Should it be counted twice?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a way to do this without resorting to a for loop but this is one solution I can think of right now. Identify the unique elements in the first row of matrix A and loop over all the elements to find the ones they are linked to in the second row.

I have assumed that you only need to identify the unique elements that the first row is linked to, hence the `unique()` function inside the for loop; if that is not the case, please remove that from the code.

```
a = [1 2 1 3 1 2 4 3 5 1; 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 7 7 8];

row1el = unique(a(1, :));

c = zeros(2, length(row1el));
for i = 1:length(row1el)
  idx = a(1, :) == row1el(i);
  linkedEl = a(2, idx);
  c(1, i) = row1el(i);
  c(2, i) = length(unique(linkedEl));
end
disp(c)
```

Comment: Nice first answer +1. Welcome to SO!

Comment: You should refrain from using `i` as the increment variable, because it conflicts with the imaginary part of complex expressions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question properly, you are not really concerned about the *values* in the second row, but the number of occurrences of the elements in row 1. This can be obtained with the `unique` and `histc` functions:

```
C(1,:)=unique(A(1,:));
C(2,:)=histc(A(1,:),C(1,:));

C =

     1     2     3     4     5
     4     2     2     1     1
```

Comment: I hadn't seen this solution. +1 for spotting how the problem can be tackled in a very simple manner. For counting repeated rows just once, you could do `A2 = unique(A.', 'rows').';` and then proceed with `A2` as in your code

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether repeated columns should be counted repeatedly or not. Consider the following data:

```
A = [1 2 1 3 1 2 4 3 5 1; 
     2 3 4 5 6 6 6 5 7 8]; %// col [3;5] appears twice
```

1. If repeated columns should be **counted according to their multiplicity**: you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

   ```
   [ii, ~, kk] = unique((A(1,:)));
   jj = accumarray(kk.', A(2,:).', [], @(x) numel(x)).';
   C = [ii; jj];
   ```

   Result with my example `A`:

   ```
   C =
        1     2     3     4     5
        4     2     2     1     1
   ```

   Or you can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

   ```
   [~, ii, jj] = find(sum(sparse(A(2,:), A(1,:), 1)));
   C = [ii; jj];
   ```

   The result is the same as above.
2. If repeated columns should be **counted just once**: either of the two approaches is easily adapted to this case:

   ```
   [ii, ~, kk] = unique((A(1,:)));
   jj = accumarray(kk.', A(2,:).', [], @(x) numel(unique(x))).'; %'// note: "unique"
   C = [ii; jj];
   ```

   or

   ```
   [~, ii, jj] = find(sum(sparse(A(2,:), A(1,:), 1) > 0));  %// note: ">0"
   C = [ii; jj];
   ```

   Result (note third column is different than before):

   ```
   C =
        1     2     3     4     5
        4     2     1     1     1
   ```

Comment: +1 for a solution that, unlike mine, handles redundancy.